# Transferring rotation from parent Object3D to child - three js

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

I have a `Mesh` nested in an `Object3D`. What I'd like to do is rotate the `Object3D` on the x and y axis during a drag, and then on release reset the `Object3D` rotation to 0, 0, 0 after transferring its rotation on to the `Mesh` inside.

My approach may be totally wrong, but it seems to work for the first movement but breaks after that. I'm thinking it could have something to do with the Eueler order.

The code I'm using is:

```
function mouseDown(e) {
    hold.x = e.pageX;
    hold.y = e.pageY;
    window.addEventListener('mousemove', mouseMove);
}

function mouseMove(e) {
    var diffX = e.pageX - hold.x;
    var diffY = e.pageY - hold.y;

    object.rotation.x = (diffY * 0.25) * RADIAN;
    object.rotation.y = (diffX * 0.25) * RADIAN;
}

function mouseUp() {
    window.removeEventListener('mousemove', mouseMove);

    cube.rotation.x += object.rotation.x;
    cube.rotation.y += object.rotation.y;

    object.rotation.x = 0;
    object.rotation.y = 0;
}
```

I also made a jsfiddle to demonstrate the exact issue: http://jsfiddle.net/BJaju/4/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To transfer the parent's world transform to the child, you need to call

```
child.applyMatrix( parent.matrixWorld );
```

So in your case, it would be

```
function mouseUp() {

    window.removeEventListener('mousemove', mouseMove);

    cube.applyMatrix( object.matrixWorld );

    object.rotation.x = 0;
    object.rotation.y = 0;
```

}

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BJaju/5/

three.js r.59

Comment: Note that this solution is no longer viable, as matrix4.rotate<axis> has been removed

Comment: Sir Could you please guide me here - I am using Swift SceneKit  - Let's say I have parent node  with some matrix applied -, inside I have the Child Node - with some matrix applied  . **Parent scale is XYX is (0.2,0.3,0.2)** then the result is not same if scale is same wrongly rotated  for XYZ , Result is correct

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a solution using Quaternions!

I have two separate transforms, like this: `baseQuaternion = (new THREE.Quaternion).setFromEuler(new THREE.Euler(-Math.PI / 2, 0, -Math.PI / 2 , 'XYZ'))`

And when multiplied, they merge and combine effects. `myMesh.quaternion = baseQuaternion.clone().multiply((new THREE.Quaternion).setFromEuler(...`

This video helped:  https://www.udacity.com/course/viewer#!/c-cs291/l-124106599/m-175393413